# Run an AirFlow task in another Docker container

Tags: docker, airflow

I am considering implementing AirFlow and have no prior experience with it.

I have a VM with docker installed, and two containers running on it:

- container with python environment where cronjobs currently run
- container with an AirFlow installation

Is it possible to use AirFlow to run a task in the python container? I am not sure, because:

1. If I use the `BashOperator` with the command like `docker exec mycontainer python main.py`, I assume it will mark this task as success, even if the python script fails (it successfully run the command, but its resposibility ends there).
2. I see there is a `DockerOperator`, but it seems to take an image, create and run a container, but I want to run a task on a container that is already running.
3. The closest answer I found is using kubernetes [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-airflow-for-containerized-data-pipelines-4d7a3c385bd), which is overkill for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BashOperator` runs the bash command on:

- the `scheduler` container if you use the `LocalExecutor`
- one of the `executors` containers if you use the `CeleryExecutor`
- a new separate pod if you use the `KubernetesExecutor`

While the `DockerOperator` is developed to create a new docker container on a docker server (local or remote server), and not to manage an existing container.

To run a task (command) on an existing container (or any other host), you can setup a ssh server within the python docker container, then use the [sshOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-ssh/stable/_api/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh/index.html) to run your command on the remote ssh server (the python container in your case).